# sort() array of unique hexadecimal numbers (string-type): unexpected results

Tags: php, arrays, string, sorting, hex

**I need a sorted array of hexadecimal numbers**. (In this case, I have 128-bit numbers encoded as 32-byte hexadecimal strings: these are IP addresses, converted into binary in_addr form, then converted into hexadecimal: IPv4 addresses have been prepended with "::" to give a single address-space.) **Sorting using the PHP built-in "sort()" function yields unexpected results on some values:**

```
$test=array();
$test[]="00000000000000000000000005275087";
$test[]="00000000000000000000000005275104";
$test[]="00000000000000000000000005274E65";
$test[]="00000000000000000000000005274F32";
$test[]="0000000000000000000000000527501C";
\sort($test);
var_dump($test);
```

**→**

```
array(5) {
  [0]=> string(32) "00000000000000000000000005275087"
  [1]=> string(32) "00000000000000000000000005275104"
  [2]=> string(32) "00000000000000000000000005274E65"
  [3]=> string(32) "00000000000000000000000005274F32"
  [4]=> string(32) "0000000000000000000000000527501C"
}
```

I think there must be a problem somewhere within the sort() function, perhaps caused by implicit type conversion (applied inconsistently within the array). However, as evidence against the idea of some individual array elements being sorted as integers or floating point numbers while others are sorted as strings (so that I would expect the results to be stable, though still out of string-sorting-order); I find that rearranging the initial array elements yields different results, and also, introducing duplicate entries can induce the sort() function to produce the correct results.

Please explain the phenomenon more fully, and suggest some elegant ways to work around this problem! Is this a bug in PHP, or a "feature" of PHP's weak type-enforcement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit of both, I suppose. The problem is that PHP is too friendly when comparing the strings containing numeric values. Quoting [**the docs**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

> If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves
>   numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the
>   comparison performed numerically.

Now consider this:

```
var_dump("5275104" < "5274E65"); // bool(true)
var_dump("5274E65" < "5274F32"); // bool(true)
var_dump("5275104" < "5274F32"); // bool(false) - WHAT?
```

In the first comparison, both values are numeric strings: the first is obvious, the second because of `E` part. They are compared as numbers, as said in the docs.

In the second comparison, however, the second operand cannot be turned into a number completely, and values are now compared as strings, so it's essentially `'E' < 'F'`. It's the same situation in the third comparison (strings are processed).

---

Fortunately, that's easy to fix:

```
\sort($test, SORT_STRING);
```

The flag tells PHP that sorting function should always use compare strings irrespectively of whether or not there are numeric values in them.

Comment: Thank you. I will be using SORT_ flags on all my sorting operations, from now on!

Comment: Yes, that's often necessary - and not only for readability. ) I've added the explanation.